# val() limit of 512 KiB

Tags: google-chrome

It appears that jQuery's val() function has a limit of 512 KiB.

Here's what I do:
I have a simple form with an input field:

```
<form id='theForm' action="foo" method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='foo'/>
</form>
```

I also have a trivial `create` function that when invoked with an argument of 16 will create a string that exceeds 512 KiB.

```
function create(n) {
    var x = '0123456789';
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x += x;
    }
    return x;
} 

> x = create(16)
> x.length
655360
```

When I assign that value to the input field and retrieve it back again (on another variable) I observe that the second variable has a length of 524288 bytes (which is *exactly* 512 KiB).

```
> $('#theForm > input').val(x)
> y = $('#theForm > input').val()
> y.length
524288
```

What am I doing wrong?

JS Bin [here](http://jsbin.com/tikosofibu/edit?html,css,js,console,output) (JS Bin uses jQuery 3.1.0 but I've also tested with 3.2.1).

### Update

This problem was encountered with Chrome 54, upgrading to Chrome 67 fixed it. So it is very likely not jQuery-related. I am removing the jquery tag.

Comment: I can't reproduce on chrome 67, neither with create(17) nor create(16)

Comment: @bambam I am on Chrome 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit)

Comment: I don't have chrome 54, a good sign to update? :-)

Comment: I can't recreate either (FF 60.0.2 - 64bit)

Comment: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/maximum-string-length mentions something of maximum string length for chrome 40, maybe that's related

Comment: If I take a number like 36 I get a Range Error, invalid string length though

Comment: @bambam 36 will result in a *huge* (as in tens of GiB) string. 16 is a bit more than half a megabyte and that's enough to show the problem.

Comment: Yeah, if just been interested what the max length in chrome 67 is. I don't think it's a jQuery, but rather the browser's limitation. I've tried until 23, that makes jsBin break though...